# Perl alternation match behaves differently with parentheses

Tags: regex, perl, alternation

Can someone explain why my match behaves differently whether or not the alternation is enclosed within a capture group?

Is this possibly due to the old version of Perl (which I have no control over, sadly), or am I misunderstanding something? My understanding was that the parentheses were a convention for some people but otherwise unnecessary in this case.

```
[~]$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.6.1 built for PA-RISC1.1-thread-multi
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2001, Larry Wall

Binary build 633 provided by ActiveState Corp. http://www.ActiveState.com
Built 12:17:09 Jun 24 2002


Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using `man perl' or `perldoc perl'.  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.com/, the Perl Home Page.

[~]$ perl -e 'print "match\n" if ("getnew" =~ /^get|put|remove$/);'
match
[~]$ perl -e 'print "match\n" if ("getnew" =~ /^(get|put|remove)$/);'
[~]$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^get|put|remove$` finds `^get` or `put` or `remove$`. So, "getnew" matches the pattern because it starts with `get`.

Whereas `^(get|put|remove)$` finds `^get$` or `^put$` or `^remove$`.

Comment: Learn something new every day. Makes sense, but I hadn't realized that the alternation would extend to those. Thanks!

Comment: if you don't actually need to capture, use non-capturing parens: `/^(?:get|put|remove)$/`

Comment: @ysth: Also good to know, thanks. In this case the capture doesn't hurt, so I'll save myself the extra couple characters.

Answer (score 2):

By design, an "or" `|` is isolated to a capture group if it is enclosed in parenthesis.

The the second regex uses parenthesis around the 3 words, so it is equivalent to the following by the transitive property:

```
if ("getnew" =~ /^get$/ || "getnew" =~ /^put$/ || "getnew" =~ /^remove$/) {
     print "match\n" ;
}
```

However, the first regex has no parenthesis, so the "or" effects the entire expression including the boundary conditions.  It matches because the first test, `/^get/`, succeeds:

```
if ("getnew" =~ /^get/ || "getnew" =~ /put/ || "getnew" =~ /remove$/) {
     print "match\n" ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You and taggon were both very close in answering, but I can only accept one answer...and taggon is just getting started. :)

Comment: @Sbrocket Heh, he's been around 5 months longer than I have, but no worries ;)